# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/xyz/mysite.com/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3796

Tags: fatal-error

I am using wpjobmanager and trying to understand why a single resume page or the preview of submitting one loads only the title and photo but nothing more. After enabling debugging. I get this error next to the photo:

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/vxyz/mysite.com/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3796

(I have searched other issues and found only this: [Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string /wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1045](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304624/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-wp-error-could-not-be-converted-to-string) )

The code section referenced in the formatting.php begins like this:

*Checks and cleans a URL.

A number of characters are removed from the URL. If the URL is for displaying
(the default behaviour) ampersands are also replaced. The {@see 'clean_url'} filter
is applied to the returned cleaned URL.

@since 2.8.0

@param string $url       The URL to be cleaned.
@param array  $protocols Optional. An array of acceptable protocols.
                        Defaults to return value of wp_allowed_protocols()
@param string $_context  Private. Use esc_url_raw() for database usage.
@return string The cleaned $url after the {@see 'clean_url'} filter is applied.*

```
function esc_url( $url, $protocols = null, $_context = 'display' ) {
$original_url = $url;

if ( '' == $url )
    return $url;

3796>>  $url = str_replace( ' ', '%20', $url );
$url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\[\]\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

if ( '' === $url ) {
    return $url;
}
```

I am not sure this relates to my main issue but perhaps if I solve this I can see the next. Any help appreciated.

Comment: WordPress, whatever its faults, does not ship with fatal errors like this. The fact that the error is occurring in a core function just tells you that you have code somewhere that is using this function incorrectly. Try switching themes and disabling plugins one by one until the error goes away. When it does, you've found the culprit. It may turn out that wpjobmanager itself is responsible. Whatever the case, you need to report the issue to the developer of the code.

Comment: Somewhere in that plugin there's going to be a call to `esc_url()` that's wrapping some other function that's returning an error instead of a string.  I've seen that happen before with things like `get_term_link()`

Comment: Well I disabled the plugins one by one with no effect, I changed to basic theme and the error didn't show and the page loaded the missing data. However installing the same theme and plugins to a new wordpress domain but using same functions.php seemed to work ok too. I assume it must be database related to a bluehost gremlin, the other linked query was bluehost. This was migrated from bluehost to dreamhost recently and already had issues with 'mu-plugins' caching which took time to find and remove. Maybe I can get some more logs on this page load error somehow. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps is an issue like this https://www.ryadel.com/en/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-wp_error-could-not-be-converted-to-string-wordpress-fix/